# general solution of second order linear de

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let 1, x and $x^2$ be solutions of second order linear non homogeneous differential equation  $-1\lt x\lt 1$. Then find the general solution.

I only know that general solution is sum of complementry fxn, and particular soltion.how do we do in this problem.

Comment: Since the general solution consists of a complementary solution, which is in the form of $c_1 f_1 +c_2 f_2$ and a particular solution, you might just subtract any two of the solutions to get $f_1, f_2 $ and use one of them as particular. For example: $c_1(x-1)+c_2(x^2-1)+1$.

Comment: @KittyL I knew you were right, I just couldn't for the life of me get it to work with my equation below. I did figure it out eventually, and I have come to the conclusion that your answer is much more efficient and elegant than mine. You should write it up as an actual answer.

Comment: Suggestion accepted. I was not very sure. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the general solution consists of a complementary solution, which is in the form of $c_1 f_1(x)+c_2 f_2(x)$ and a particular solution $p(x)$, you might just subtract any two of the solutions to get $f_1(x),f_2(x)$ and use one of them as particular.

Notice that if $$F_1''(x) + p(x)F_1'(x) + q(x)F_1(x) = g(x)$$ and $$F_2''(x) + p(x)F_2'(x) + q(x)F_2(x) = g(x)$$

Then subtraction of the two gives you that $F_1-F_2$ is a solution of the homogeneous equation.

As long as you can find two independent solutions of the homogeneous equation using subtraction, they form the complementary part.

So $c_1(x−1)+c_2(x^2−1)+1$ is a general solution to the nonhomogeneous equation.

Comment: In general if we know two soln of nonhomogenous linear eqn of nth order, then does thier subtraction gives a soln of homogenous part? Is that correct to say?

Comment: Yes. Look at the two equations in my answer. If you change them to higher order linear equations, you can still subtract to cancel the nonhomogeneous term, and factor out the coefficient terms $p, q$, etc. to get $F_1 -F_2$ as solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation should look something like this:
$$
f''(x) + p(x)f'(x) + q(x)f(x) = g(x)
$$
where $p, q$ and $g\neq 0$ are some functions that you (in general) know. In this case, however, we have to *find* them. If we insert $f(x) = 1$, we get that
$$
q(x) = g(x)
$$
If we insert this into the equation with $f(x) = x$ we get
$$
p(x) + xg(x) = g(x)\implies p(x) = (1-x)g(x)
$$
Now using this with $f(x) = x^2$, we get
$$
2 + (1-x)g(x)\cdot 2x + g(x)\cdot x^2 = g(x)\\
g(x) = -\frac{2}{(1-x)\cdot 2x + x^2} = -\frac{2}{x}
$$
All of these are valid because we know that $f(x) = 1, x$ and $x^2$ are all solutions to the equation, and that is what being a solution to the equation means.

The original equation therefore looks like
$$
f''(x) - \frac{2(1-x)}{x}f'(x) - \frac{2}{x}f(x) = -\frac{2}{x}
$$
Since we want $-1<x<1$, I would say it's better to get rid of the $x$ in the denominators to get
$$
xf''(x) - 2(1-x)f'(x) - 2f(x) = -2
$$
I've never learned anything about second order differential equations with non-constant coefficients, so I don't know how to solve this, but maybe you can?